# Compiling C++ Program with MYSQL.h in Linux

Tags: c++, mysql, compiler-errors, redhat

I'm following the example from [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-connect-mysql-c-api-program.html) and my code is identical.

When I type mysql_config --libs and mysql_config --cflags into the console as he explains, I get the same output as he shows.  Yet, when I try to compile using

> g++ -o output-file $(mysql_config --cflags) test.cpp $(mysql_config
>   --libs)

I get the errors:

> test.cpp:3:25: error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
>   test.cpp: In function âint main()â:
>   test.cpp:6: error: âMYSQLâ was not declared in this scope
>   test.cpp:6: error: âconnâ was not declared in this scope
>   test.cpp:7: error: âMYSQL_RESâ was not declared in this scope
>   test.cpp:7: error: âresâ was not declared in this scope
>   test.cpp:8: error: âMYSQL_ROWâ was not declared in this scope
>   test.cpp:8: error: expected `;' before ârowâ
>   test.cpp:13: error: âmysql_initâ was not declared in this scope
>   test.cpp:17: error: âmysql_real_connectâ was not declared in this scope
>   test.cpp:18: error: âmysql_errorâ was not declared in this scope
>   test.cpp:19: error: âexitâ was not declared in this scope
>   test.cpp:22: error: âmysql_queryâ was not declared in this scope
>   test.cpp:23: error: âmysql_errorâ was not declared in this scope
>   test.cpp:24: error: âexitâ was not declared in this scope
>   test.cpp:27: error: âmysql_use_resultâ was not declared in this scope
>   test.cpp:31: error: ârowâ was not declared in this scope
>   test.cpp:31: error: âmysql_fetch_rowâ was not declared in this scope
>   test.cpp:35: error: âmysql_free_resultâ was not declared in this scope
>   test.cpp:36: error: âmysql_closeâ was not declared in this scope

When I try 'whereis mysql' it shows /usr/bin/mysql, /usr/lib/mysql and /usr/share/mysql, but I'm not sure where mysql.h is located exactly.  The admin of the server I'm working on said he installed MySQL and I can indeed create/manipulate tables using phpMyAdmin.

Also, please give me suggestions about this particular problem.  I'm aware of C++ wrappers for MySQL but I'm trying to just use the C API for now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the code compiles fine (I just had to include stdlib.h for exit()). MySQL headers should be in /usr/include/mysql, and since you got the same output for "mysql_config --cflags", you probably have a missing/broken package.

Try reinstalling the packages he list on the begining of the article, or check in which package the headers are in your distro. I'm am using Ubuntu, and here the package with the headers is libmysqlclient15-dev.

Comment: Yes, I believe you are right.  After fishing around some more it appears that I don't have the right packages to develop an application using MySQL.  I'm a little wary of installing them myself though since the admin of the server installed MySQL there to start with.  Although, I do have 'admin' access to the server, I wonder if there is any potential harm in my adding them.

Comment: @Aaron You will need libmysqlclient on the server, but the devel headers you need just on the machine you are developing.

Comment: Oh I see.  The devel headers are just to compile the application locally, and then I can upload them to server to run right?

Answer (score 1):

The file ought to be somewhere under /usr/include/mysql. You could try searching for it using something like `find /usr -name mysql.h`

Comment: Hm, I don't have a mysql directory in /usr/include.  In this case, I thinks it's possible the admin didn't install all the necessary packages.